# How can I display telemetry data?

Tags: f1-2020

Recently, while looking at the F1 2020 settings, I noticed an entry related to UDP Telemetry.

I guess this is intended to collect/display additional telemetry data somehow, but I didn't figure out how.

I'm sure I have enabled the feature, could you please tell me how to display the data?

Comment: Your edit has made your question a little vague: do you want to know how to enable it, or what the different settings mean, or something else? Can you show a screenshot of what you're referring to?

Comment: Hi @Joachim, I edited the question in order to explain better what I'm looking for. Basically I am able to enable the feature, but I don't know where data is displayed while racing.